# How to clear or make/remove a new instance of an html dialog

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html dialog box with a form which is opened via dynamically created unordered list items. This part works fine, but i enter information in the form and submit, it works. but if i click on another item in the unordered list to open the dialog box and click submit, it submits with the previous data + the data entered, and then if i click on a third item to open the dialog it send data from the first + second + third forms. and on and on.why is this? how do i properly close or clear the dialog box so that for each time i open it its like the very first time.

i have tried `paymentDialog.close();` i have tried `paymentDialog.empty`

The dialog in html :

```
<dialog class="mdl-dialog" id="paymentDialog">
<div class="mdl-dialog__actions">
            <button type="button" class="mdl-button" id='paymentSubmit'>Submit</button>
            <button type="button" class="mdl-button" id='close'>Cancel</button>
          </div>
</dialog>
```

The javascript :

```
the dinamically created ul item :
jobLi3.addEventListener('click', function(){
        paymentDialogClick(doc.data().veh_id)
    });
```

to open the dialog :

```
var paymentDialog = document.querySelector('#paymentDialog');
paymentDialog.showModal();
```

testing the result :

```
paymentDialog.querySelector('#paymentSubmit').addEventListener('click', function() {
       // this result will be added over and over as i open the dialog with different elements in the list.
        console.log("total "+theChargeTotal.toString());
      });
```

expected result : 
everytime i open a dialog box it shouldn't still have data from the previous time i opened it ( the previous instance should be destroyed)
actual result :
the console log shows the result of the previous dialog + the current dialog

the full function what is called when a li is selected :

```
//paymentdialog:
function paymentDialogClick(jobId){
    var theChargeTotal = 0;
    var thePaymentTotal = 0;

    if (! paymentDialog.showModal) {
        dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(paymentDialog);
      }
      db.collection('job_charges').where('job_id', '==', jobId).get().then(
          function(myChargesDocs){
              myChargesDocs.forEach(function(currentCharge){
                  theChargeTotal += currentCharge.data().total;
              })

              db.collection('job_payments').where('job_id', '==', jobId).get().then(
                  function(myPaymentsDocs){
                      myPaymentsDocs.forEach(function(currentPayment){
                          thePaymentTotal += currentPayment.data().paymentTotal;
                      })
                      //
                      var theAmountLeft = theChargeTotal - thePaymentTotal;
              var labelTotal = paymentDialog.querySelector('#currentTotal');
              if(theChargeTotal == 0){
                labelTotal.textContent = "No Charges On This Job.";
              }else{
                labelTotal.textContent = "Current Bill : "+theAmountLeft.toString();  
              }

              paymentDialog.showModal();
                  }
              )
          }
      )

      paymentDialog.querySelector('#close').addEventListener('click', function() {

        paymentDialog.close();

      });
      paymentDialog.querySelector('#paymentSubmit').addEventListener('click', function() {

        console.log("total "+theChargeTotal.toString());
      });
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your code in js fiddle. that would be really helpful to solve the problem quickly.

Comment: @MuraliNepalli its quite alot of code. alot of it im not authorized to publicize. I have added the function that is called when an `li` element is clicked

Comment: @MuraliNepalli without considering the code though, how would you recommend i clear or remove an instance of a dialog box ?

Comment: @SkyentGroup I am guessing that you are submitting data via AJAX since if you were using form submission, the values could not be retained in the DOM. That presupposition on the table, it sounds like you are creating multiple copies of the dialog so that each time the form submits, it finds multiple copies of the form fields, with data. What would happen if you either: (1) Have only one copy of the dialog that you populate each time before opening, and then clear field values before closing; or at least (2) Clear each field value back to '' before hiding/closing the dialog?

Comment: @gibberish im not using ajax. the dialog box is already created in html but its just one. I think maybe clicking on the elements create a new instance of the dialog box that has all duplicate fields. when you say "clear each field" do you mean doing something like this : `theChargeTotal ="";`

Comment: Yes, that's what I had in mind. There is no need to create a new dialog box each time and destroy it after use. I always use a single dialog box, populate the fields (or allow the user to input into the fields), submit the data to the back end via ajax, clear the field values `$('#id_of_input_field').val('');` (jQuery), and hide the dialog. Next time it is needed, repeat process

Comment: @gibberish so your saying dont use `dialog.close()` but `dialog.hide()` instead ?

Comment: I am not sure what `dialog.close()` does... it might just hide the dialog. Is this a jQueryUI dialog, or is it self-rolled? What is ***in*** the `.close()` method (i.e. specifically what does it do)? At any rate, the key point was to clear out the field values just before you close the dialog, and see what that does. AFK now until morning. : )

Comment: @gibberish im doing this in pure javascript, no matter what i do its like instances of the dialog are being created everytime i open the dialog so even though i clear all fields, the previous instances get the info from the current dialog. Is all hope lost with this one? should i just tear this down and do the whole thing again in jQuery ? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a work-around. What i did was i reloaded the element with jQuery JUST after closing it like so :

```
paymentDialog.close();
$("#paymentDialog").load(" #paymentDialog > *");
```

its not efficient but now i can move forward with my project. If anyone has a better way to get rid of the dialog instances please feel free to let me know.